# Ansible-Playbook: Error Message "Unable to find any of pip3 to use. pip needs to be installed"

Tags: ansible

I try to install boto3 via ansible in my playbook.

I tried to create a new user on my host.

```
- name: "test user"
  hosts: test
  tasks:
   - name: "install boto3"
      pip:
        name: boto3
        executable: pip3
```

I got this message :

```
{"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to find any of pip3 to use.  pip needs to be installed."}
```

Comment: Do you have `pip` installed on the remote test host?

Comment: @xenlo Yes I installed pip

Comment: Is the behavior the same if you specify the full path to the pip3 executable? For example, `/usr/bin/pip3` or `/usr/local/bin/pip3`?

Answer (score 13):

Install Python3-pip  before the failing step

```
- name: install pip3
  apt: name=python3-pip state=present
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to install `pip3`, which is different from `pip`.
In ubuntu, it comes with package `python3-pip`:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: I find that I get this on a new install on ubuntu 18.04 after having just installed python3-pip.  If I run again it works fine.  I'm not sure how to fix.

Answer (score 2):

First of all these are the requirements of pip ansible module as specified on ansible docs,
Docs Link: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pip_module.html

- pip
- virtualenv
- setuptools

Secondly, you have mentioned pip3 in executable field, which makes it to use python3, and it may be possible that python3 is not installed on the host and python2 is available.

So, either leave that field or check the proper python version installed and update the value of executable field accordingly.

Comment: no it isn't there is no mention of depedencies or how to even setup that thing in the first place.

Comment: @FelipeValdes, Please check the link shared in the answer, and check the requirements section.